# ag-grid - Add Row with infinite row model

Tags: ag-grid

I need to add a new row in the ag-grid with infinite scroll. There are similar questions for example this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932246/ag-grid-remove-row-with-infinite-row-model). However my case is very different.
I am using inline editing in the ag-grid and have a button to add a new row. There is a submit button which the user may or may not press.
So the data on the server is not immediatly modified when the new row added to the client site.
When I was using a client side model everything was trivial - I get the rows from the server and can add new rows to the array and call setRowData on ag-grid. However this function is not available with infinite scroll. I am using angular 2+ if that matters.

I tried to call applyTransaction however got an error in the console:

*g-Grid: updateRowData() only works with ClientSideRowModel. Working with InfiniteRowModel was deprecated in v23.1 and removed in v24.1*

Seems like a-grid simply removed the functionality with nothing to replace with.

Answer (score 3):

i personally didn't use agGrid with angular, but if you are using `infiniteRow` model, you can use the `setDataSource` method that would force your table to refresh it's data.

the `setDataSource` method accepts an object with two minimum parameters :

```
{
  rowCount: null,
  getRows: (params) =>{
    // here you can do your server call or, you can pass the data you want instead.  

  // you also need to do one thing at the end of your row generation, call this method
//`rows` is the array of rows you want to show, `totalRowsNumber` is the number of rows in total, including those that are not shown (the ones in later pages)
params.successCallback(rows, totalRowsNumber);
  
  } 
}
```

setting the dataSource is trivial using the `gridApi.setDatasource(dataSourceObject)`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. It is a bit messy and complex for example how to handle scrolling out the modified rows, I hope there would be some straightforward way similar to apply transaction in the client side mode

Comment: Can you share the solution? I’m also stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, AG Grid still doesn't support this simple (in my opinion) use-case and forces you to re-fetch currently displayed chunk from the server.

This introduces quite an overhead (in my opinion) as you will query and fetch `<chunk_size>` data from server when in reality you could've just client add/remove/update the row into the table pessimistically or optimistically without extra chunk fetch overhead which is totally unnecessary.

So in summary: After the operations, you re-fetch the chunk by using `gridApi.refreshServerSide()`, which also has option to purge cache which will introduce those annoying loading rows.

Worst part is that `refreshServerSide` is a `void` so you can't even have callbacks out of the box but you need to manage it some other way to improve UX.